# jQuery unveil load images in viewport added via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jQuery unveil http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/ plugin
to lazy load images. But I'm confused about this behavior:

If I load images via AJAX and append them into viewport, I need to scroll webpage to load images. The images do not load unless I scroll.

I tried to solve it via recall function to load images after they are written via .html(), but nothing happens:

Here is part of code, which I'm trying to use:

I redefined html function to be able to connect callback to it and try to call function lazy_load() after .html() is done.

Do you have any ideas, how to solve it? Thank you

```
// create a reference to the old `.html()` function
var htmlOriginal = $.fn.html;

// redefine the `.html()` function to accept a callback
$.fn.html = function(html,callback){
  // run the old `.html()` function with the first parameter
  var ret = htmlOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
  // run the callback (if it is defined)
  if(typeof callback == "function"){
    callback();
  }
  // make sure chaining is not broken
  return ret;
}
var lazy_load = function(){
            $(document).find('img.lazy-load').unveil();
    };
products_wrapp.html(data.products_html, function(){ 
                    lazy_load();
});
```

COMPLETE UNVEIL INTEGRATION:

I load unveil plugin, after jquery.js, before `</body>` element.

Here is code:

```
// I edit html function to use callback at this function...

// create a reference to the old `.html()` function
var htmlOriginal = $.fn.html;

// redefine the `.html()` function to accept a callback
$.fn.html = function(html,callback){
  // run the old `.html()` function with the first parameter
  var ret = htmlOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
  // run the callback (if it is defined)
  if(typeof callback == "function"){
    callback();
  }
  // make sure chaining is not broken
  return ret;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   /* --------------------------------
       lazy load
       -------------------------------*/
    var lazy_load = function(){
            $(document).find('img.lazy-load').unveil();
    };
    lazy_load(); // call function for first time


    // load products, put them into products_wrapp element, after
    // html() is done -> apply lazy_load
    products_wrapp.html(data.products_html, function(){ 
                    lazy_load();
                });
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you need to add a callback to the `.html()`? This method is synchronous/blocking.

Comment: I tried to do it, because i thought, that lazy_load is called while .html() is executing => images are not in html so lazy_load can't be applied to any element

Comment: can nobody in this community answer this?

Answer (score 0):

The `unveil` plugin is designed to lazily load images on scroll. If you look at [source code](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/blob/master/jquery.unveil.js) it was designed this way:

```
function unveil() {
  var inview = images.filter(function() {
    var $e = $(this);
    if ($e.is(":hidden")) return;

    var wt = $w.scrollTop(),
        wb = wt + $w.height(),
        et = $e.offset().top,
        eb = et + $e.height();

    return eb >= wt - th && et <= wb + th;
  });

  loaded = inview.trigger("unveil");
  images = images.not(loaded);
}
```

If you want to load the rest of the images rather than wait on scroll you can simply manually trigger them:

```
$("img").trigger("unveil");
```

Comment: Thank you @peterdotjs And do you have any idea, how to recognize images which are in viewport and apple trigger on them?

Comment: @hanis the `unveil` library actually already figures that out for you. See above  the filter function is filtering for objects in the viewport. To trigger them simply execute `$("img").unveil();`

Comment: As you can see, I'm  trying to do it:
**products_wrapp.html(data.products_html, function(){ 
                    lazy_load();
});**
but it doesn't work. I need to scroll to show images

Comment: @hanis when you execute `lazy_load ` do you get image results returned for  `$(document).find('img.lazy-load')`? You'll need to either step through the code or post a jsfiddle. As far as I can tell it looks fine.

Comment: I recognized, that same behavior is also when I open new page with images, not only ajax.

Comment: There is something wrong with your integration of the unveil library. I've used it in the past and it works very simply. The library itself is very small.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I post my integration bellow my question

Comment: @hanis I've pretty much helped as much as I can. You should post a complete jsfiddle example if you would like more debugging help.